# Compile libgcc.a and libstd++.a for 32 bits

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, libstdc++, libgcc

Good afternoon,

If I'm here today is because I encounter some compilation problems.
For a project, I would like to compile gcc in order to have libgcc.a and libstd++.a for 32 bits.
Unfortunatly I have some problems.
Here are the command lines I used to configure and compile the wanted libraries:

```
CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" CFLAGS="-O1 -march=i686 -gtoggle" CXXFLAGS="-O1 -march=i686 -gtoggle" ; ../src/gcc/gcc-8.1.0/configure --prefix=/path/compiled/x86/O1/gcc --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-static i686-linux-gnu

make all-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

When I execute last command line I have those errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:985: libgcc_s.so] Error 1
```

My machine:
Archlinux 64 bits, up to date
Output of gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (GCC)
```

Thank you for your help !

EDIT: ANSWER HERE

SO for those who wants to know how to compile libgcc and libstdc++ for 32 on a x86_64 machine:

```
./configure --target=$TARGET --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers --prefix=/path/
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make all-target-libstdc++-v3

make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
make install-target-libstdc++-v3

make clean
```

Then go to the folder containing your new installation, you'll normaly have two folders: lib32 and lib64. Inside lib32, there is the 32 bits version of libgcc and libstdc++ and in lib64, their 64 bits version.

Enjoy !